# Chrome Extension send message internal network

Tags: javascript, networking, google-chrome-extension, chat

I want to send plain text messages to other users' Chrome Extension over the internal network using IP's, like a chat-application. Is this possible using Chrome Extensions? I did a lot of research, unfortunately without success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about the extension. But it can be achieved with [Chrome app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/multicast).

Comment: 1) WebRTC 2) a simple message server on the network that all the clients connect to.